# Is it possible to create an element that can overlap another one in Quill?

Tags: javascript, wysiwyg, contenteditable, quill

I'm trying to create a custom resize blot that can resize another element like 'td' in quill editor, but I have no idea what kind of blot could achieve this. In general when doing the resize we're using another div to control the element's size we want to change. But now in quill, I don't know what blot type I should use, because the resize div should be placed in the same position with the element we want to resize, and none of the current blot type for quill ('block', 'inline', 'embed') is suitable for this case. I sure can create a container blot which include the current 'td' element, but isn't it'll build a relationship between this div with 'td'? I want to keep the table's original relationship instead of insert something else inside of it.

I have no idea how to deal with this case. Any enlightenment would be really appreciated!